# TableView not scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I know there are multiple threads about this but none of the solutions have worked for me. I have a `TableView` in my `iOS` app that is populated with a `plist` that contains about 70 cells. In my `Storyboard` I have scrolling enabled, bounces, and bounces vertically but the list does not scroll past the 6th or 7th cell. Is there a setting in the Storyboard that I am missing or should something go in the .m file?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1; 
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return plistItems.count;
}
```

Comment: Did you check to see if the number of rows is set correctly,

Comment: Its calculated here: `(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Comment: I have an `NSMutableArray` that I get from my `plist` and `numberOfRowsInSection` is set to that array .count

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the code that implements your `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`

Comment: How much of this are you doing in code and how much on the storyboard?  What's the height of the tableview?

Comment: I set the delegate and datasource to my MasterViewController.

So far all I did was set the tableview in the storyboard and all the detailview items (just text fields). I created the list and made it populate my table view in the code. So far that's all I have done. And I am completely new to iOS development so I apologize if this is hard to follow

Comment: Can you should `numberOfRowsInSection:` method?

Comment: I edited my question to include that method, as I said though I just have it set to my MutableArray that I get from my plist

Comment: Could it be that `plistItems` doesn't have all the data you expect? What is its size (that is, what does `[tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]` return?

Comment: It returns 72, which is the correct size of my plist

Comment: Can you reload table after array fill?

Comment: What do you mean by that exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to scroll in stimulator. You Need to scroll with 3 fingers. Hope this works for you.